# xlmElementTree duplicated items

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an xml file which I am trying to parse. For the moment, I successfully parsed it and returned it in a DataFrame.

However, it appears I don't have the same number of rows between the different elements, and this appears to be due a duplication of certain rows/elements which have several values.

For example, I have a row which element `rule` :
    . has an `attrib` of `{'code' : 'RI0200'}`

and then two `child elements` `value` :
    . with `attrib` of `{'test' : 'Id'}` and `{'test': 'Result'}`

The problem is that these child elements "value" come in the xml code sometimes 2 times or sometimes 3, 4 or 5... hence the discrepancy in the count of rows at the end.

My question is : how can attach each `value` to a single `rule` and thus duplicate the `rule` as many row as there are `value` ?

When looping with `root.iter()`, I can see there is some kind a attachment point:

```
    < Element 'xxxxxxx' at 0x0000000xxxx>
```

My first attempt would be to access that last part, but I don't know how.

e.g.

Case 1: 
`<Element 'Rule' at 0x00000xxx..>`
`<Element 'Value' at 0x00000xxx..>`
`<Element 'Value' at 0x00000xxx3..>`

Case 2: 
`<Element 'Rule' at 0x00000xxx..>`
`<Element 'Value' at 0x00000xxx..>`
`<Element 'Value' at 0x00000xxx..>`
`<Element 'Value' at 0x00000xxx..>`

Case 3: 
`<Element 'Rule' at 0x00000xxx..>`
`<Element 'Value' at 0x00000xxx..>`
`<Element 'Value' at 0x00000xxx..>`

Case 4: 
`<Element 'Rule' at 0x00000xxx..>`
`<Element 'Value' at 0x00000xxx..>`
`<Element 'Value' at 0x00000xxx..>`
`<Element 'Value' at 0x00000xxx..>`
`<Element 'Value' at 0x00000xxx..>`

code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\CRC\test2.XML')
root = tree.getroot()
    lst_rule2 = []
    lst_msg = []
    lst_value_name = [] 
    lst_value_result = []

   for rule in root.iter('rule'):
       lst_rule2.append(rule.attrib)

   for msg in root.iter('message'):
       lst_msg.append(msg.attrib)

   for value in root.iter('value'):
      lst_value_name.append(value.attrib)
      lst_value_result.append(value.text)

   import pandas as pd
   df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst_rule2)
   df2 = pd.DataFrame(lst_msg)
   df3 = pd.DataFrame(lst_value_name)
   df4 = pd.DataFrame(lst_value_result)

   df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4], axis=1)

print(len(lst_rule2), len(lst_msg), len(lst_value_name), len(lst_value_result))
```

returns `1413 1413 3630 3630`

XML (part):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fconR.png)

Comment: Can you show the code you use for parsing? And how do you build the DataFrame?

Comment: I just add the code. I hope it helps

Comment: The code is still incomplete, where are the input and the parsing part? What is `root`?

Comment: might this be only because of the XLM file's conception ? meaning some rows were dropped or, inverselly, others dupplicated ?